# NotificationCompat.Builder is deprecated what to do?

Tags: java, android, notifications

i'm new to programming, learning from the book "Head First Android ",
there was a problem in the chapter 18:
When used NotificationCompat.Builder, Android Studio issues such a message
'Builder(android.content.Context)' is deprecated , description below,
there is also a photo of the
displayed message

Thank you in advance for your help

[NotificationCompat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c45he.png)

[NotificationCompat.Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofOYD.png)

''''

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="16dp"
   tools:context="com.hfad.joke.MainActivity">

 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/question"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

''''

```
package com.hfad.joke;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }

  public void onClick(View view) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, DelayedMessageService.class);
      intent.putExtra(DelayedMessageService.EXTRA_MESSAGE,
            getResources().getString(R.string.response));
      startService(intent);
   }
}
```

''''

```
 package com.hfad.joke;

 import android.app.IntentService;
 import android.app.NotificationManager;
 import android.app.PendingIntent;
 import android.content.Intent;

 import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

  public class DelayedMessageService extends IntentService {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 5453;

    public DelayedMessageService() {
        super("DelayedMessageService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                wait(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String text = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        showText(text);
    }

    private void showText(final String text) {
        //Creating a notification builder
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                //problem here, shows NotificationCompat.Builder strikethrough!
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.question))
                        .setContentText(text)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setVibrate(new long[] {0,1000})
                        .setAutoCancel(true);
        //Create action
        Intent actionIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                0,
                actionIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(actionPendingIntent);
        //Issuing a notification
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
        getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }

    }
```

''''

Answer (score 0):

> NotificationCompat.Builder is deprecated

`NotificationCompat.Builder` is not deprecated. See [the class documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder).

> Android Studio issues such a message 'Builder(android.content.Context)' is deprecated

That particular constructor is deprecated, and has been for quite some time. That is covered in [the documentation for that constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder?hl=en#Builder(android.content.Context)). The documentation also shows the alternative: [the two-parameter constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder?hl=en#Builder(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)), where you pass a channel ID along with the `Context`. You will need to define that channel using `NotificationManager` or `NotificationManagerCompat`. The sample apps in [this repo directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/Notifications) will demonstrate using channels.

> i'm new to programming, learning from the book "Head First Android "

If you are referring to the second edition of that book, it came out 3 years ago. Given the lead time for traditionally-published books like that, it means that it was written around 3.5 years ago. In Android, that is a fairly long time. You are likely to encounter a variety of these sorts of deprecations and other changes.